# Starting EC2Cluster with dask_cloudprovider

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dask

I'm trying to start an EC2Cluster using dask_cloudprovide, i have already done it for fargate and i figured that for EC2 would be similar.
Problem:
I tried to do it the most basic way possible:

```
from dask_cloudprovider.aws import EC2Cluster
from dask.distributed import Client
cluster = EC2Cluster(
    n_workers=1, 
)
```

But even with this basic code i stil get the following output:

> Creating scheduler instance 2023-03-22 17:24:14,805 -
> distributed.deploy.spec - WARNING - Cluster closed without starting up
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:320,
> in SpecCluster._start(self)
> 319     self.scheduler = cls(**self.scheduler_spec.get("options", {}))
> --> 320     self.scheduler = await self.scheduler
> 321 self.scheduler_comm = rpc(
> 322     getattr(self.scheduler, "external_address", None)
> 323     or self.scheduler.address,
> 324     connection_args=self.security.get_connection_args("client"),
> 325 )
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:68,
> in ProcessInterface.**await**.._()
> 67 if self.status == Status.created:
> ---> 68     await self.start()
> 69     assert self.status == Status.running
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py:88,
> in SchedulerMixin.start(self)
> 87 self.cluster._log("Creating scheduler instance")
> ---> 88 ip = await self.create_vm()
> 89 self.address = f"{self.cluster.protocol}://{ip}:{self.port}"
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ec2.py:164,
> in EC2Instance.create_vm(self)
> 162     vm_kwargs["Placement"] = {"AvailabilityZone": self.availability_zone}
> --> 164 response = await client.run_instances(**vm_kwargs)
> 165 [self.instance] = response["Instances"]
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py:371,
> in AioBaseClient._make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
> 370     error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
> --> 371     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
> 372 else:
>
> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling
> the RunInstances operation: User data is limited to 16384 bytes
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[8], line 1
> ----> 1 cluster = EC2Cluster(
> 2     n_workers=1,
> 3 )
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ec2.py:605,
> in EC2Cluster.**init**(self, region, availability_zone, bootstrap,
> auto_shutdown, ami, instance_type, scheduler_instance_type,
> worker_instance_type, vpc, subnet_id, security_groups,
> filesystem_size, key_name, iam_instance_profile, docker_image, debug,
> instance_tags, volume_tags, use_private_ip,
> enable_detailed_monitoring, **kwargs)
> 603 self.scheduler_options["instance_type"] = self.scheduler_instance_type
> 604 self.worker_options["instance_type"] = self.worker_instance_type
> --> 605 super().**init**(debug=debug, **kwargs)
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py:297,
> in VMCluster.**init**(self, n_workers, worker_class, worker_options,
> scheduler_options, docker_image, docker_args, extra_bootstrap,
> env_vars, security, protocol, debug, **kwargs)
> 294 self.worker_options["extra_bootstrap"] = extra_bootstrap
> 295 self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
> --> 297 super().**init**(**kwargs, security=self.security)
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:286,
> in SpecCluster.**init**(self, workers, scheduler, worker,
> asynchronous, loop, security, silence_logs, name, shutdown_on_close,
> scheduler_sync_interval)
> 284 if not called_from_running_loop:
> 285     self._loop_runner.start()
> --> 286     self.sync(self._start)
> 287     try:
> 288         self.sync(self._correct_state)
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:345,
> in SyncMethodMixin.sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout,
> *args, **kwargs)
> 343     return future
> 344 else:
> --> 345     return sync(
> 346         self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
> 347     )
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:412,
> in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
> 410 if error:
> 411     typ, exc, tb = error
> --> 412     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
> 413 else:
> 414     return result
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:385,
> in sync..f()
> 383         future = wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
> 384     future = asyncio.ensure_future(future)
> --> 385     result = yield future
> 386 except Exception:
> 387     error = sys.exc_info()
>
> File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/gen.py:769, in
> Runner.run(self)
> 766 exc_info = None
> 768 try:
> --> 769     value = future.result()
> 770 except Exception:
> 771     exc_info = sys.exc_info()
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py:339,
> in VMCluster._start(self)
> 329 self.worker_spec = {
> 330     self._new_worker_name(i): self.new_spec for i in range(self._n_workers)
> 331 }
> 333 with warn_on_duration(
> 334     "10s",
> 335     "Creating your cluster is taking a surprisingly long time. "
> 336     "This is likely due to pending resources. "
> 337     "Hang tight! ",
> 338 ):
> --> 339     await super()._start()
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:329,
> in SpecCluster._start(self)
> 327 except Exception as e:  # pragma: no cover
> 328     self.status = Status.failed
> --> 329     await self._close()
> 330     raise RuntimeError(f"Cluster failed to start: {e}") from e
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py:453,
> in SpecCluster._close(self)
> 450     logger.warning("Cluster closed without starting up")
> 452 if self.scheduler:
> --> 453     await self.scheduler.close()
> 454 for w in self._created:
> 455     assert w.status in {
> 456         Status.closing,
> 457         Status.closed,
> 458         Status.failed,
> 459     }, w.status
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/generic/vmcluster.py:60,
> in VMInterface.close(self)
> 58 async def close(self):
> 59     """Destroy a VM."""
> ---> 60     await self.destroy_vm()
> 61     await super().close()
>
> File
> ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask_cloudprovider/aws/ec2.py:228,
> in EC2Instance.destroy_vm(self)
> 223 boto_config = botocore.config.Config(retries=dict(max_attempts=10))
> 224 async with self.cluster.boto_session.create_client(
> 225     "ec2", region_name=self.region, config=boto_config
> 226 ) as client:
> 227     await client.terminate_instances(
> --> 228         InstanceIds=[self.instance["InstanceId"]], DryRun=False
> 229     )
> 230     self.cluster._log(f"Terminated {self.name} ({self.instance['InstanceId']})")
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Can anyone tell me what's wrong because by reading the documentation i don't see any required parameters, even reading the error it looks like some InstanceId parameter is missing , but there is no such parameter in the dask_cloudprovider documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is this one:

> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RunInstances operation: User data is limited to 16384 bytes

This is a known problem, see https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/249 . The current solution is not to use TLS in your dask configuration (`security=False`) and ensure network safety in other AWS-specific ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i have read the github topic you sent and i think it might be it , i had no time to test it yet , but once i do i will give some feedback.

Comment: Just to confirm that it did the trick